# How do I convert an array of structs into an array of derived type with ISO C BINDINGS?

Tags: fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, derived-types

I have the following test C library:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct mystruct {
    int a;
    double  b;
};

struct mystruct *return_array_of_structs(int *size);

struct mystruct *return_array_of_structs(int *size) {

    int i;
    struct mystruct *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct)*10);
    
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        ptr[i].a = i+1;
        ptr[i].b = (i+1)*1.0L;
    }
    
    *size=10;
    return ptr;
}
```

And the following module intended to be compiled with `f2py`:

```
module test_c_lib

        use iso_c_binding
        implicit none

        type :: t_mystruct
            integer :: a
            real(8) :: b
        end type
        
contains

        subroutine test()

                use iso_c_binding
                
                type(c_ptr)     :: ret_c_ptr            
                integer         :: length
                
                ! Interface to C function
                interface                        
                        type(c_ptr) function c_return_array_of_structs(a) bind(C, name="return_array_of_structs")
                                import
                                integer(c_int) :: a
                        end function
                end interface

                ! Call C function               
                ret_c_ptr = c_return_array_of_structs(length)

        
        end subroutine

end module
```

The following makefile compiles this:

```
f_mod.so:       f_mod.f90 c_lib.o
                f2py -c f_mod.f90 c_lib.o -m f_mod

c_lib.o:        c_lib.c
                gcc -c -fpic c_lib.c -o c_lib.o
```

I can load the library in Python normally and execute the `test()` subroutine without problems.

```
import f_mod
f_mod.test_c_lib.test()
```

But I do not how to convert `ret_c_ptr` into an array of derived type `t_mystruct` that I can normally operate as an array in Fortran. Any hint?
Note: the question is related to `iso c bindings` and Fortran, not to `f2py` or its integration with Python.

Comment: Have you looked at using `c_f_pointer` (with the shape argument as in previous questions)?

Comment: I was trying to use that, I ended up with the solution but without using interoperable types in the struct. Unsure if that can be done or might have some side effects. Apparently it works.

Comment: @M.E. That's the sort of thing you will probably get away with ... until you don't. Using interoperable types will also get rid of the non-portable real( 8 ).

Comment: Using the interoperable definition of the struct works too as anyway you need to further encapsulate the output arrays from the array of structs as individual arrays (`f2py` does not support returning array of structs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a C pointer and want to associate a Fortran pointer with the target of that C pointer, you want to use `c_f_pointer` to do that association. `c_f_pointer` doesn't (generally) care whether the type is an intrinsic one or not, or scalar or not.

Let's define the Fortran derived type as an interoperable<sup>1</sup> one:

```
type, bind(c) :: t_mystruct
  integer(c_int) :: a
  real(c_double) :: b
end type
```

and then have a Fortran pointer array of that type:

```
type(t_mystruct), pointer :: ptr_f(:)
```

With `ptr_c` pointing to a suitable lump of memory we can do the association:

```
call c_f_pointer(ptr_c, ptr_f, [length])
```

to make `ptr_f` an array of shape `[length]` pointing to the C target.

---

<sup>1</sup> Being interoperable isn't necessary, but it's certainly helpful to be if it can be.

Comment: I haven't used the `bind(c)` and the `c_int` `c_double`, instead I have used a regular derived type, it seems to work. Do you think that would generate a problem? I am not sure if `f2py` can handle interoperable types to present the interface to python.

Comment: You can use a non-interoperable type (if it's 
"the C address of a storage sequence that is not in use by any other Fortran entity" for example) but that won't be as flexible. Either way, you want to avoid `real(8)`.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer to this question is the one provided by francescalus above, however I include the complete excerpt of code with the functions exposed by `f2py` to Python.

`f2py` will not allow to return numpy arrays of derived types (which would be a numpy vector of a custom dtype), so you need to return individual vectors per field. Also `f2py` can not return allocatable arrays without explicit size, therefore this function needs to be split into two calls, one to get the length and another one to get the actual array.

While these are clear limitations of `f2py` this allows to call directly Fortran functions (or C encapsulated functions as in this example) and get numpy arrays as return values.

The code is not optimised as it implies invoking the C function twice, maybe there is the possibility to use sort kind of static variable like in C, so the second invoke would already had computed the values, although I do not know:

1. if that is possible at all in Fortran
2. if that is possible within the context of a shared object (which is what `f2py` creates from the module)

As there is not that many examples around `f2py` this might be useful for someone:

```
    module test_c_lib
    
            use iso_c_binding
            implicit none
            
            type, bind(c)  :: t_mystruct
                    integer(c_int) :: a
                    real(c_double) :: b
            end type
            
    contains

        subroutine get_array_len(l)

                use iso_c_binding
                
                integer, intent(out)    :: l
                
                type(c_ptr)               :: ret_c_ptr            
                integer                   :: length
                
                ! Interface to C function
                interface                        
                        type(c_ptr) function c_return_array_of_structs(a) bind(C, name="return_array_of_structs")
                                import
                                integer(c_int) :: a
                        end function
                end interface

                ! Call C function               
                ret_c_ptr = c_return_array_of_structs(length)
                l = length
        
        end subroutine

        subroutine get_array(l, a, b)

                use iso_c_binding
                
                integer, intent(in)     :: l
                integer, intent(out)    :: a(l)
                real(8), intent(out)    :: b(l)         
                
                type(c_ptr)               :: ret_c_ptr            
                type(t_mystruct), pointer :: f_ptr(:)
                integer                   :: length
                
                ! Interface to C function
                interface                        
                        type(c_ptr) function c_return_array_of_structs(a) bind(C, name="return_array_of_structs")
                                import
                                integer(c_int) :: a
                        end function
                end interface

                ! Call C function               
                ret_c_ptr = c_return_array_of_structs(length)
                call c_f_pointer(ret_c_ptr, f_ptr, [length])
                a = f_ptr%a
                b = f_ptr%b
        
        end subroutine

end module
```